# Update column only if value doesnt exist in other column

Tags: mysql, sql-update, case

I got a program, sending 2 strings to PHP ($lic for a license, and $hwid for a hardwareid) with those 2 parameters, I want to update the columns "hardwareid1, hardwareid2 or hardwareid3" (one where value is NULL with every login) but I dont want to fill 2 columns (for example hardwareid1 and hardwareid2) with the same value! so if the value from $hwid already exists in one of those 3 columns, no updated is needed.

```
UPDATE  license
SET     hardwareID3 = CASE WHEN hardwareID1 IS NOT NULL AND
                                hardwareID2 IS NOT NULL AND
                                hardwareID3 IS NULL
                                THEN '$hwid' 
                                ELSE hardwareID3 END,
        hardwareID2 = CASE WHEN hardwareID1 IS NOT NULL AND 
                                hardwareID2 IS NULL 
                                THEN '$hwid' 
                                ELSE hardwareID2 END,
        hardwareID1 = CASE WHEN hardwareID1 IS NULL 
                                THEN '$hwid' 
                                ELSE hardwareID1 END
WHERE   code = '$lic'
```

Solution:

```
 AND '$hwid' NOT IN (COALESCE(hardwareID1,hardwareID2,hardwareID3, 0))
```

Comment: Some more background on what you're trying to achieve here would be useful. It looks to me like you have a modelling problem, which is making your SQL and ultimately the rest of your system harder to write.

Comment: Is only one column NULL or are there more? If there is only one a relatively easy solution is available. But why not use a seperate table to store the relation between license and hardwareid?

Comment: Hardwareid1, hardwareid2, hardwareid3
are ALL NULL.

Comment: you can use `COALESCE()` [see here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bae5/1)

Comment: Working! thanks a thousand times! I used to be oracle developer and its frustrasting to look at the mysql documentation -_-

Comment: @491243 Sorry to ask again, but the COALESCE documentation says that the return should be either the value or NULL. Somehow I get always NULL as return no matter how many column are filled. And I just saw that if hardwareID2 got a value, hardwareID3 will get the same if the value doesnt change. I reallya dont know why because I think I understand your CASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will update hardwareId2 and hardwareId1 even when id3 is set. Don't know what you wanted to reach there.

Take a look at `COALESCE()` MySQL function for building even more complex statements satisfying your needs :)

Comment: I got a program, sending 2 values to PHP ($lic license, and $hwid for a hardwareid) with those 2 parameters, I want to update the columns "hardwareid1, hardwareid2 or hardwareid3" (1 where value is NULL with every login) but I dont want to fill 2 columns (for example hardwareid1 and hardwareid2) with the same value! so if the value from $hwid Ill get already exists, no updated is need.

Comment: Looks like you need something like that: if(id1 IS NULL && id2 != $hwid AND id3 != $hwid) THEN SET ID1 = $hwid... And the same "IFs" for the other 2 ids.

Answer (score -1):

Add a condition to the where clause:

```
update ...
set ...
where code = '$lic'
and '$hwid' not in (coalesce(hardwareID1,0), coalesce(hardwareID2,0), coalesce(hardwareID3,0))
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13f8c/1)

Comment: @LeeLoo意 Thanks for the fiddle. Fixed now. See edit and new fiddle link.

Comment: @PoscheL It works now. The problem was when nulls are in a list, any operation (`IN` or `NOT IN`) is false